# the already highly coveted slots

Tags: word-meaning

Does "slot" here mean "position"? Or "assignment"?

> Massachusetts’s COVID-19 vaccine appointment portal crashed on Thursday, as hundreds of thousands of residents became newly eligible to reserve **the already highly coveted slots**. Across the commonwealth, frustrated residents reacted with a question: Why didn’t the state anticipate and prevent this?

> Source:  [Harvard News](https://news.harvard.edu/gazette/story/2021/02/so-why-did-the-state-vaccine-reservation-system-crash/?utm_source=twitter&utm_campaign=hu-twitter-general&utm_medium=social)

Comment: It's the second definition [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slot) - a time slot for getting vaccinated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slot is a long thin hole which you fit things into. So we have slot machines where you put money into the slot to play the game or buy the product. In the case you mention it is used to refer to time slots, intervals of time sufficient to put something into. Neither of your suggestions, position or assignment, is quite right here.